# Updating create-react-app app, but cannot find react-scripts in package.json

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

The title says it all.

To update my app, which was made with create-react-app, I have to update react-scripts. But, I cannot find this in my package.json. I've even tried installing it manually even though it was not there in the first place and should have been. No luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

can you upload s screenshot what is the message they show you once you run it ?